# arithmetic overflow error converting decimal with int variable in where clause (bug?)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm thinking this is a strange bug in SQL Server (2012) but please help me with a sanity check.  This is an overly simplified version of an ugly query in one of our stored procedures (the real query has 13 tables). Table3.r is decimal(12, 2).

```
DECLARE @elid int, @bpid int, @tid int, @r decimal(14, 10);
SELECT @elid = 123, @bpid = 456, @tid = -1;
SELECT TOP 1 @r = t3.r -- implicitly converts dec 12,2 to dec 14,10
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.blah = t2.blah and t2.elid = @elid
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.wth = t3.wth and t2.tid = t3.tid
WHERE t1.bpid = @bpid
    AND t3.tid > @tid
ORDER BY t3.tid;
```

Sample table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (bpid int IDENTITY(1, 1), blah int, ...)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (elid int IDENTITY(1, 1), blah int, wth int, tid int...)
CREATE TABLE Table3 (..., wth int, tid int, r decimal(12, 2))
```

Table3 has roughly 80k records.  99.999% of the time the query works.  But in at least one strange case, where t3.r = 24.79 (though I don't believe the value 24.79 itself is problematic), it causes this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Then I found that if you simply hard code -1 in the WHERE clause it works fine:

```
....
    AND t3.tid > -1;
```

Or if you simply select t3.r (rather than trying to convert to 14,10) it also works fine:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t3.r
...
    AND t3.tid > @tid; -- var is still in the WHERE clause
```

Or if you set @tid to a value that yields only a single record (it typically returns 3 or 4 records, then grabs TOP 1) it also works:

```
SELECT @elid = 123, @bpid = 456, @tid = 9;
SELECT TOP 1 ...
```

I know you're thinking "just make @r 12,2" and yes that works but I'll spare you the details of why it's not that simple.  However making @r 20,10 is a viable option and does solve the problem.

I swear I'm not crazy and I wish I could post a video to prove this is happening.  I've seen strange behavior with variables before but nothing like this.  Any ideas?  Does this sound like an obscure bug?

Here's the real query (abbeviated with mangled table names, told you it was ugly):

```
SELECT TOP 1 @r = pc.pc_cost
--SELECT TOP 1 pc.pc_cost, CONVERT(decimal(14, 10), pc.pc_cost)
from BP
join EL on bp_id=el_bpid and el_id = 65232907
join PL on bp_plid=pl_id and pl_type=1 and pl_exchange=1
join BU on bu_id=bp_buid
join SL ON sl_id=bu_slid and sl_subtype=pl_subtype and sl_plantype=1
join ER on er_eeid=el_eeid and er_cgeid>1 and er_cgeid>1
join XR on er_id=xr_erid
join EG on sl_egid=eg_id
join SM on sm_eid=eg_eid and sm_egid=eg_id and sm_subtype= er_subtype
join XS on xs_id=sm_xsid and xs_phase>1
join XD on xd_xsid=xs_id
join CN on cn_id=bp_cnid
join PC on pc_cnid=cn_id and pc_tierid=xd_tierid and er_id = pc_erid
where bp_id= 314853
and pc_tierid > @tid
order by pc_tierid ASC;
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain 24.79 is not the problem, but wanted to mention what the actual value was.  The problem with @tid is not specifically -1 either, the same error occurs when I set it to any value that yields more than 1 record in the result set (the real query uses SELECT TOP 1).
Sorry I was trying to be brief in my question.  I'll update it accordingly.

Comment: Can you add all the tables definition to your post?

Comment: The real 13 tables have a total of 579 cols.  I tried to limit my simplified version to only the values that seem relevant. In the real query every value in the JOINs or the WHERE clause (other than t3.r) is an int (mostly IDENTITY cols).  I'll add some simple table defs to my question above.  Thanks.

Comment: This is entirely possible `DECLARE @r1 decimal(14, 10),  @r2 decimal(12, 2); SET @r2 = 10000; SET @r1 = @r2` you have no control over where it does the cast a single out of range value could cause that even if it isn't the `TOP` ONE.

Comment: @anthony444 I have another question.  If you run the same query many times, the result is different (I mean, sometimes you receive an arithmetic error and sometimes it works?)...  If you have an example identified, maybe you can generate a cursor with your query and cast the values manually to check specifically the row that is raising the error?
Another option is that the exception is caused by other field and not by the conversion (Just trying to see out of the box) :D

Comment: @CrApHeR @elid and @bpid are actually procedure parameters representing values from IDENTITY cols (PKs) with innumerable possible value combinations.  Today we encountered one particular combination (which happens to yield t3.r=24.79) which causes this error 100% of the time (unless I hard-code "... > -1").  The procedure has been called millions of times since its last ALTER and we haven't noticed this before.  It's also strange that I can target the individual row in Table3 (without any JOINs) and it works just fine: `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(14,10), t3.r) FROM Table3 t3 WHERE t3.myPk = 789`

Answer (score 0):

These questions always interest me so i tried to reproduce the problem you are seeing. So far the below code is my only succesfull result of getting this error:

```
use demo 
go
if object_id('dbo.numbers', 'U') is not null
    drop table dbo.numbers
create table numbers (
    nid int primary key
   ,d12_2 decimal(12, 2))
insert dbo.numbers
select * from (values 
(1, 1234567890.12),
(2, 12345)) i(n,d)
go
declare @d14_10 decimal(14, 10)
select @d14_10 = (select top 1 d12_2
                    from dbo.numbers
                    where nid = 1)
go
declare @d14_10 decimal(14, 10)
select @d14_10 = (select top 1 d12_2
                    from dbo.numbers
                    where nid = 2)
```

With the following output:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 15
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 20
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

The only way I have been able to get this error is by attempting to convert something that won't fit in the new type (duh...) Because precision is increasing (spaces behind the dot) it is impossible to get into trouble there. This leaves me with the conclusion there must be a record  in your data that has t3.r => 10000

This seems strange at first because you have a known value for t3.r which is smaller. However... I wonder how you determined that value? is it possible that 24.79 is that last value that ran succesfully?

The only other option is that the problem is caused outside of the scope of your demoonstrated example.

Comment: Thanks @Tristan. I added the "real" query (abbreviated with mangled table names) to the original question above.  I know it's 24.79 because I can grab the value without converting it, or if @r is declared as decimal(12,2), or if I simply hard-code -1.

Comment: is there any other reference to this t3.r in the original code? that would be highly relevant but im having some difficulty trying to read the code you posted. (very well done on the mangling ;))

Comment: Ah, sorry.  t3.r is the equivalent of pc.pc_cost in the "real" query.  I pasted the query with the CONVERT function I was using to test.  I updated the "real" query above in a way that should make things more clear.

Comment: 1 more question, since the error doenst specify which col is causing the error, is it possible one of the join cols is of a different datatype then another?

Comment: Good question.  Yesterday I double checked every column type in the JOINs and they are all int's.